# Make the text bold in option that matches the data in VUEJS

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

Since i am learning the VUEJS, i am stuck at a place where i need to make the sentence bold inside a `<li>` that matches the text from the database.

Here is the code:

```
              <div>
                i. Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum .
                Your answer?
                <ul>
                  Answer:
                  <li>option 1</li>
                  <li>option 2</li>
                  <li>option 3</li>
                </ul>
              </div>
```

I am getting a value from the database and i am getting it using `{{anwer.option}}` and i want to show in this that if `{{anwer.option.option1}}` is option 1 then need to show the current option along with the other options too. For example:

```
            <div>
            i. Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum .
            Your answer?
            <ul>
              Answer:
             <strong><li>option 1</li></strong>
              <li>option 2</li>
              <li>option 3</li>
            </ul>
          </div>
```

Comment: Although your question doesn't have enough information to work on, I believe you're able to use `font-weight` property with a value of `bold` in your CSS.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use conditional class and style, https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/class-and-style.html:

```
<template>
<li :class="{bold-font: ifMatch('option 1')}">option 1</li>
</template>
<script>
methods:{
    ifMatch(option){
        return this.anwer.option === option
    }
}
</script>
<style>
.bold-font:{
    font-weight: bolder;
}
</style>
```

Comment: i have attached an image in the question, i am getting those red line errors. please advise

Comment: sorry but not seen any pic